# add an event to an element

Tags: javascript

I am a new learner of javascript, the following code is from the javascript definitive guide.

```
function addEvent(elem, evtType, func)
{
   if (elem && typeof(elem) == "object")
   {

      if (elem.addEventListener)
      {
         elem.addEventListener(evtType, func, false);
      }

      else
      {
         elem["on" + evtType] = func;
      }
   }
}
```

why it add

```
  if (elem.addEventListener)
  {
     elem.addEventListener(evtType, func, false);
  }
```

but the `window.onload` works ok under every browsers. the following is my test example.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
         window.onload=myFuntion();
        function myFuntion(){
            alert("test");
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>

    <h1> testtste </h1>
</body>
```

it works ok under IE ff.

Comment: Have a look at jQuery library. It makes DOM manipulation much easier, but it also offers events, animations, ajax... etc etc

Comment: @ppumkin At least someone tries to understand how things work :).

Comment: Some Quirksmode read: [Traditional event registration model](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_tradmod.html), [Advanced event registration models](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Direct assignment is not robust.

… and your code isn't running the function on load anyway. It is running it immediately and assigning the return value (`undefined`) to the `onload` object.

If we fix that, then a demonstration:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
      window.onload=myFuntion;

      function myFuntion(){
            alert("test");
       }
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      window.onload=myOtherFunction;

      function myOtherFunction(){
            alert("test2");
       }
  </script>
```

The event gets overwritten. Only one function will fire.

… the example from the definitive guide isn't very good though. It falls back to direct assignment (which makes it rather pointless) instead of trying the old proprietary APIs (e.g. [attachEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536343%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for IE 8 and lower) that would allow multiple event binding.